# Is it possible to keep track of timer in standby mode?

Tags: qt, qtimer

I'm using timer to put the system in standby mode on inactivity of 15 secs,Is it possible to use same timer to keep track in standby mode,because I need to shutdown the system on inactivity of 1 min.

```
time_t PlayerIdleTime;
if(_curTime - this->PlayerIdleTime >15)
{
     standby();
}
else if(_curTime - this->PlayerIdleTime >60) //but it is not working 
{
     poweroff();
}
```

How to keep track using same timer in staandby mode?

Answer (score 1):

If **_curtime-this->PlayerIdleTime > 60** is true, then **_curtime-this->PlayerIdleTime > 15** must also be true; you're never reaching the **else** part because the **if** is always satisfied.

Swap the tests around and it might work.

Comment: Yes IF condition will be always true,I should need to keep track of timer in standby mode also.once it reaches 1 min, need to call poweroff function. Is it possible?

Comment: if (timer > 60s) poweroff(); else if (timer > 15s) standby(); -- does this explain my meaning better?

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this, as the commenter told you.

```
time_t PlayerIdleTime;
if(_curTime - this->PlayerIdleTime >60) 
{
     poweroff();
}
else if(_curTime - this->PlayerIdleTime >15)
{
     standby();
}
```